# How to translate completion suggestions by clicking the word on suggestion bar?

Tags: javascript, html, web, autocomplete

I can only use HTML, CSS, and Javascript for this project. The app is a translator. I did most of it, but I have a problem with translating the word which I select in the suggestions (I did create suggestion thing on javascript), it translates the text when I put it on my own, but idk how to do it by selecting it on the suggestion part, any help would be appreciated. HTML code is below.

```js
function checkfortranslate(){
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    input = input.toLowerCase();

    if(input=="able"){
        output.innerHTML = "привет";
    }
    else if(input=="about"){
        output.innerHTML = "привет";
    }
    else if(input=="allow"){
        output.innerHTML = "привет";
    }
    else if(input=="above"){
        output.innerHTML = "благодарю вас";
    }
    else if(input=="abroad"){
        output.innerHTML = "привет";
    }
    else if(input=="accident"){
        output.innerHTML = "привет";
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>SIMPLE ENGLISH TRANSLATOR</h2>
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Write text to translate" onkeyup="checkfortranslate()">
    <ul class="list"></ul>
    <div id="output" style="display: inline;">[Translation]</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'setting it on the suggestion"?

Comment: like google/yandex and other translators, for example when i put "ab" letters, it shows "did you mean about?", and when i click "about", it translates and displays it on the right side, i am trying to do same thing.

Comment: You say in the question that you implemented some sort of suggesting mechanism, but I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: it is on the javascrit side, let me share it, it is kinda long that's why i didn't share.

let input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=> {

Answer (score 0):

You can use html [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) element.

```
<datalist id="input" type="text" placeholder="Write text to translate" onkeyup="checkfortranslate()">
     <option value="able">
     ...
     <option value="accident">
    </datalist>
```

**Edit:**

```
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Write text to translate" onkeyup="checkfortranslate()" list="list">
 <datalist id="list">
     <option value="able">
     ...
     <option value="accident">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: i did, but i can't see the box to put text, the page it is empty now.

Comment: Sorry, you should use `<input list="[listID]" [attributes]>` and the datalist only definie with set attribute `id` to `[listID]`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but my problem isn't listing them. My problem is; i want it to be like google translate, like when i click on the for example "able", it should translate it and display on the <div id="output" style="display: inline;">[Translation]</div> element. It only translates when i write the word on my own, not by clicking.

Comment: You killed it dude, thank you for the help! You are the best. i did put something wrong yesterday i guess. Appreciate it!

Comment: Once and for all, i need a help about making the bar hidden when i click on the bar, i mean it shouldn't show up when i click on the text bar, it should appear when i put a letter.

Comment: You can add this: `inputElement.onfocus=function() {if(inputElement.value=''){inputElement.removeAttribute('list')}}` and  add to function `checkfortranslate` this line `if(input!=''){inputElement.setAttribute('list','[listID]')}` - the `inputElement` variable content the input element.